# comparison between pointer and integer ('int *' and 'int')

Tags: objective-c

I am confused as to why I get this warning:

I intiate matchObsFlag with:

```
int *matchObsFlag=0;
```

but when I run this line:

```
    if (matchObsFlag == 1)
```

I get this warning. Any ideas?

Comment: int does not need a pointer, just do int a = 10;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You surely get a warning because you did not cast 1 as such `(int*) 1` so you test an equality between different things : an address and an int.

So it is either `if(matchObsFlag == (int*)1)` or  `if(*matchObsFlag == 1)` depending on what you wanna do.

Comment: Note however that testing  for `matchObsFlag == (int*)1` is probably a mistake, as it will test if the pointer is pointing to the adress `0x00000001` in memory.

Answer (score 10):

```
int *matchObsFlag=0;
```

The type of `matchObsFlag` is `int*` while the constant literal is of type `int`. Comparison between the unrelated types is causing the warning.

`matchObsFlag` is a NULL pointer. `matchObsFlag` needs to point to a valid memory location if you wish to compare the value pointed by the pointer.

```
int number = 1;
matchObsFlag = &number;
```

Now, to compare the value, you need to dereference the pointer. So try -

```
if (*matchObsFlag == 1)
{
  // ...
}
```